# boto3 S3 limit upload speed of a large file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is there a way to limit the available bandwidth for the Python Boto3 S3 file upload process?
I am uploading some pretty heavy files (each file is approximately 5 GB in size)
The upload process consumes my entire bandwidth for a while. This is causing some issues.

Is it possible to set a hard limit on how much upload speed boto3 can use? Either an absolute limit like 10 mbps or a relative limit of 10% of available capacity?

Answer (score 1):

Investigate the configuration options available in [TransferConfig](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html), including:

> The maximum number of concurrent S3 API transfer operations can be tuned to adjust for the connection speed. Set the max_concurrency attribute to increase or decrease bandwidth usage.